# Xpath-time based functions with working example

Tags: java, xml, web-services, apache, xpath

Hi i am working on  [this example](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-years-from-duration) ,as per syntax ok but i didn't get any working solution.

Can some give me  time based operations working example like current date,Subtraction of current dates using **xpath.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath 1.0 or 2.0?

Read anything on XPath 2.0 and it's full of examples of date and time arithmetic. For example you can do `current-date() - xs:date('2014-01-01')` and the result will be `xs:dayTimeDuration('P20D')`.

By contrast if you want to do anything in XPath 1.0 you're largely out of luck because there's no support for this.

Comment: Hi Michael thank you, But i am working on XPath 1.0,How can i do in XPath 1.0..Please guide me .

Comment: XPath 1.0 does not have any functionality for handling dates and times. Since you're using Java, you can easily upgrade to XPath 2.0, e.g. by installing Saxon.